# Method reference does not fulfil the functional interface contract but it compile. How it is possible?

Tags: java-8, java-stream, method-reference

In the class below, I pass the method reference `WordCounterEx::accumulate` as second parameter to the reduce method. The signature of reduce method is:

```
<U> U reduce(U identity,
             BiFunction<U, ? super T, U> accumulator,
             BinaryOperator<U> combiner);
```

Thus the second parameter of reduce method, must fulfil the BiFunction recipe.
But the passed accumulate method is not BiFunction (it has only one parameter). Why it still compile?

```
public class WordCounterEx {
    private final int counter;
    private final boolean lastSpace;

    public WordCounterEx(int counter, boolean lastSpace) {
        this.counter = counter;
        this.lastSpace = lastSpace;
    }

    public int countWords(Stream<Character> stream) {
        WordCounterEx wordCounter = stream.reduce(new WordCounterEx(0, true),
                //HOW CAN THIS WORK? here must come BiFunction - R apply(T t, U u);
                WordCounterEx::accumulate,
                WordCounterEx::combine);
        return wordCounter.counter;
    }

    public WordCounterEx accumulate(Character c) {
        if(Character.isWhitespace(c)) {
            return lastSpace ?
                    this :
                    new WordCounterEx(counter, true);
        } else {
            return lastSpace ?
                    new WordCounterEx(counter+1, false) :
                    this;
        }
    }

    public WordCounterEx combine(WordCounterEx wordCounter) {
        return new WordCounterEx(counter + wordCounter.counter
                ,wordCounter.lastSpace /*does not matter*/);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`accumulate()` is an instance method, and you refer to it by class name and method name (not by instance and method name). So if I wanted to call the method you are giving me, I would usually do `myEx.accumulate(myCh)`. Thus I provide two things, the `WordCounterEx` instance and the character. Therefore, used this way the method counts as a `BiFunction<WordCounterEx, ? super Character, WordCounterEx>`.

If instead you had given me for example `this::accumulate`, the object to call the method on would have been given (`this`), and it could no longer be used as a `BiFunction` (in my Eclipse I get “The method reduce(U, BiFunction, BinaryOperator) in the type Stream is not applicable for the arguments (WordCounterEx, this::accumulate, WordCounterEx::combine)”).

Comment: Note that in Java 8 you could pass `this` as an argument, which matches the signature perfectly: `public WordCounterEx accumulate(WordCounterEx this, Character c)`. This is equivalent to the version without `this` as an argument, like in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The `WordCounterEx#countWords` method can be rewritten as follows:

```
public int countWordsWithInstance(Stream<Character> stream) {
    WordCounterEx wordCounter = stream.reduce(new WordCounterEx(0, true),
            this::accumulate,
            WordCounterEx::combine);
    return wordCounter.counter;
}

public WordCounterEx accumulate(WordCounterEx wc,Character c) {
    if(Character.isWhitespace(c)) {
        return wc.lastSpace ?
                wc :
                new WordCounterEx(wc.counter, true);
    } else {
        return wc.lastSpace ?
                new WordCounterEx(wc.counter+1, false) :
                wc;
    }
}
```

In this case the accumulate method must have `WordCounterEx wc` in its signature

Comment: That is true. As a variant of the same you may declare `accumulate()` `static` and refer to it as `WordCounterEx::accumulate` (as in your question) (this works because, as you know, `static` methods are called without an object).